# Error 404 on logout function (Ion Auth) using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

Calling this function to redirect me to the login webpage throw me '404 Error : the page you requested was not found'. I have followed the same steps that i followed for another application and it worked fine. Any Ideas?

**Link**

```
<li>
                            <a href="<?= base_url('auth/logout') ?>">Salir</a>
                        </li>
```

**Ion Auth function**

```
// log the user out
public function logout() {
    $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

    // log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    // redirect them to the login page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
}
```

**Base_url**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/herba/';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
public function logout() {
    $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

    // log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    // redirect them to the login page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect(base_url('auth/login'), 'refresh');
}
```

please make sure 
`http://localhost/herba/auth/login` exist

Also check with `index.php`

`http://localhost/herba/index.php/auth/login`

Comment: Thanks! It worked with 'http://localhost/herba/index.php/auth/login' but i don't understand, it should work with 'http://localhost/herba/auth/login' as my old proyect. Why is this happening?

Comment: please check your `.htaccess` file. I think the issue is there.

Comment: Where is the issue? `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_rewrite enabled and allow_override for this project in your apache settings?

Comment: I am using xampp and i did the following: http://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/   but it doesn't work